# SSIS Script Component or Script Task Write To Job History Log

Tags: sql-server, logging, ssis, sql-agent-job, script-component

- I am using SQL server 2008 R2.
- I have a scheduled job that executes an SSIS Package - running in SQL Agent.
- I want to log messages that happen in the scheduled job.
- I want to log messages from Script Component or Script Task.
- I do not want to log ONLY errors, I want to log success messages such as "Processed X records".
- I do not want to build custom tables or anything.
- Ideally, I want to see these messages in the Job History log

Answer (score 4):

You can send messages directly to the Job History Log. It will show up as follows in the Job history log:

[image]

For Script Tasks use the following code:

```
Dts.Events.FireWarning(0, "Message header", "Message Body", String.Empty, 0)
```

For Script Component use the following code:

```
Dim myMetadata As IDTSComponentMetaData100
myMetadata = Me.ComponentMetaData
myMetadata.FireWarning(0, "Message Header", "Message Body", "", 0)
```

You will need to enable "Include step output in history (see below)

- Right-Click on Job >> Steps >> Edit >> Properties >> Advanced >> Check "Include step output in history"

You will need to enable Warning Messages for the SSIS package (see below)

- Right-Click on Job >> Steps >> Edit >> Properties >> Command Line Add "W" to /REPORTING

---

Enabling "Include step output in history":

[image]

---

Enabling Warning Messages:

[image]